# installing docx module failed with error code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, installation, pip

When trying to install the module docx I get the **error code 1**. Also tried to install it from file.

I am using **Python 3.7.0a4 64bit**, **pip is uptodate as well as setuptools**

I tried to install a different module and got the same error.

Anyone have an idea?

Here is the error:

Command ""e:\programme\python 3.7.0a4 64bit\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;____file____='C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-at8ydfxt
\lxml\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(____file____);code=f.read().repl
ace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, ____file____, 'exec'))" install --rec
ord C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-90k4qvt1-record\install-record.txt --
single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\User
s\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-at8ydfxt\lxml\

Comment: I can't read those screenshots and I don't think anyone else can either.  Repeat the exercise, edit your question, and paste your error messages into your question as text. We can't help you if we can't read the error.

Comment: If by any chance your reason for not copying the output was that the Windows console is not very user friendly, I can recommend https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ for example.